# angularjs $watch cannot detect change of Property in an object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, prototype

I'm setting watch for `$scope` object will not trigger `$watch` change event unless the whole value is changed

**Example :**

```
//Some where in .run function i set rootScope and set $watch too.
$rootScope.config = {date:'11/4/2015',moreValues:'etc'};

//setting $watch
$rootScope.$watch('config',function(new,old) {
console.log('config value changed :)',new);
});

//----->Inside Controller----------

//NOw THIS WILL NOT TRIGGER $watch
$rootScope.config.date = 'another day';

//Same as this, it will also not trigger $watch
var temp = $rootScope.config;
temp.date = 'another day';
$rootScope.config = temp;

//YET THIS WILL WORK JUST FINE :) AND WILL TRIGGER $watch
var temp = angular.copy($rootScope.config);
temp.date = 'another day';
$rootScope.config = temp;
```

can someone tell me why is this behavior? is there a better way to trigger `$watch` on change of object Property?

Answer (score 5):

You can use $watchCollection, or pass a third param as true

```
$rootScope.$watch('config',function(value,old) {
console.log('config value changed :)',value);
}, true);
```

or

```
$rootScope.$watchCollection('config',function(value,old) {
console.log('config value changed :)',value);
});
```

- [Scope $watch() vs. $watchCollection() In AngularJS](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2566-scope-watch-vs-watchcollection-in-angularjs.htm)